# How to get value from table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to get the date(ETA) value of each row of the table and compare it to todays date the issue here is whenever I try to get the cell value it shows as blank

```
<div class="tableDiv" align="left">

         <table id="example" class="display" align="center">
           <thead>
             <tr style="color: #D2002E; background: #FFCC01;">
               <td>Date</td>
               <td>RR</td>
               <td>Origin</td>
               <td>Destination</td>
               <td>CNEE</td>
               <td>Status</td>
               <td>PUDate</td>
               <td>HAWB</td>
               <td>Pieces</td>
               <td>Weight</td>
               <td>ETA</td>
               <td>AWB</td>
               <td>Billed</td>
               <td>Details</td>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody id="table_body_Ops">
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
```

here where I get the values for each row from database (firebase)

```
  $("#table_body_Ops").append("<tr><td>" + ConfirmedDateValue +
      "</td><td class=\"valueRRField\">" + RRValue +
      "</td><td>" + OrgValue +
      "</td><td>" + DestValue + "</td><td>" + CustNameValue + "</td><td>" + ShipmentStatusValue + "</td><td>" + PUDateValue +
      "</td><td>" + HAWBValue + "</td><td>" + PiecesValue + "</td><td>" + WeightValue + "</td><td class=\"getETA\" >" + ETAValue +
      "</td><td>" + AWBValue + "</td><td>" + BilledValue + "</td><td><Button class=\"lisnClickOps\">" + "Expand" + "</Button></td></tr>");
```

here where I am trying to get the value of ETA cell value to later compare it to todays date but all I am getting is just blank

```
$('#table_body_Ops').each(function() {

    var etaDateValue = $(this).closest("tr").find(".getETA").text();

    window.alert(etaDateValue);

 });
```

Comment: instead of getting value from DOM, as you are getting value from DB, you can store that in an array before displaying

Comment: I am not trying to get the value here from the database I am trying to get it from the table cell , the values for each column and row already been received from the database

Comment: Are you getting the values after the appen?.I mean if you are getting the data from firebase, possible that you are getting them async over an AJAX call and the code that fetch the data is not inside the callback.

Comment: apparently i was executing the code before the table had any rows values from firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#table_body_Ops tr').each(function() {

    var etaDateValue = $(this).find(".getETA").text();

    window.alert(etaDateValue);

});
```

What you were doing in your code was looping through each instance of all the table bodies called `#table_body_Ops` - well, there is only one.

What you want to do is loop through all table rows of that table body, so specify the `tr` in the `.each` function, so js will loop through all those table rows (not table bodies).

Then, inside the `.each()`, the `$(this)` will refer to each table row - and from there you search for the cell that you want.

#### Update:

TEST: Modify your code like this:

```
/*
$('#table_body_Ops tr').each(function() {

    var etaDateValue = $(this).find(".getETA").text();

    window.alert(etaDateValue);

});
*/
alert('All is well'); //If this alert does not display, problem is elsewhere in your code.
```

Comment: Tried it but window alert doesn't appear

Comment: tried it with `console.log()` but no difference doesn't show in the log

Comment: Let's check if the error is in the above code, or somehwere else. Comment out the code and substitute an alert or a console.log - I'll update my answer to show you what I mean. Answer updated - please check.

Comment: `alert('All is well');` is appear fine when reloading the page

Comment: Change the alert to: `alert( $('#table_body_Ops tr').length );`  Let's see if the `#table_body_Ops` element has rows...  Does that routine (that we commented out) run on page refresh, or on button press, or ?

Comment: i tried `alert( $('#table_body_Ops').length );` its showing 1

Comment: That could be why that routine abends -- if it just runs on `document.ready` (without being triggered by a button press or something) then there are zero rows to `.each()` over...  What event triggers the rows being added to the table? That's where you should put that routine.

Comment: Yess this what was happening moved the code to be executed after the values added to the table a silly mistake on my part Thank you!!

Comment: but i am getting the first row being looped three times

Comment: What do you mean, specifically? Mind you, it does not appear that this new matter relates to *this* question, specifically, does it? Perhaps it should be asked in a different question so that other members can also view/assist (you will get more help, faster). *(But please post a link to the new question in a comment below this answer)*

Comment: Please also review your comments below this answer and delete most of them, just to keep things tidy for future readers. *(For example, I will delete my last two comments since they do not directly relate to helping solve this question)*